# Flutter ImagePicker opens in selfie mode when CameraDevice.rear selected

Tags: flutter, flutter-image

Would anyone know why the ImagePicker.pickImage keeps opening in the wrong **camera direction**? I'm using [ImagePicker (0.6.5+2)](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker#-readme-tab-)

```
 var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
        source: ImageSource.camera,
        imageQuality: 60,
        preferredCameraDevice: CameraDevice.rear);
```

I've also tried `CameraDevice.front`. Both enum values of CameraDevice give the same camera direction.

I'm running an Android 10 (Samsung S9)  device.

It looks like this is a bug, because I ran it on my iPad and it doesn't have this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its been confirmed as a bug after I submitted an [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/55644) on `flutter/flutter` repo.